# "cannot convert 'SinglyLinkedList<int>::node*' to 'int*' in assignment compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors."

Tags: c++, c++98

Error

> t.cpp: In constructor 'SinglyLinkedList::SinglyLinkedList(T*,
>   size_t) [with T = int]': t.cpp:29:   instantiated from here Line 51:
>   error: cannot convert 'SinglyLinkedList::node*' to 'int*' in
>   assignment compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

in the line shown below

```
   node * lastNode = new node;
   lastNode->val = *arr;
   lastNode->next = NULL;
   for (T * pa(arr+1), * pb(arr+n); pa != pb; ++pa)
   {
      node * thisNode = new node;
      thisNode->val = *pa;
      thisNode->next = NULL;
      lastNode->next = thisNode; // error 
      lastNode = thisNode;
      delete thisNode;      
   }
```

Full code is here: http://codepad.org/gZ2KnrUM

Can't figure out what is syntactically incorrect about that line.

Bonus question: Is there a way of shorthanding initialization of a `struct` with `new`? I want to be able to make lines like

```
node * lastNode = new node;
lastNode->val = *arr;
lastNode->next = NULL;
```

into a single line if possible. I know that if I was create it on the stack then I could do

```
node lastNode = { *arr, NULL m};
```

but is there an equivalent brace initialization for creating with `new`?

Comment: Short hand for creating the node will be to use the same syntax as before, but put `new node` infront of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to assign a type of `node *` to a variable of type `int *`.

Your node code for node should be:

```
struct node 
{  
    T val;
    node * next;
};
```

As for the "shorthand initialization" I would just use a constructor.

```
class node 
{ 
    T val;
    node * next;

public:
    node(T val, node * next)
    : this->val(val)
    , this->next(next)
    {};
};

node * lastNode = new node(*arr, nullptr);
```

Or a c++11 initializer:

```
node * lastNode = new node { *arr, nullptr };
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the line

```
lastNode->next = thisNode;
```

and the error is that

```
cannot convert 'SinglyLinkedList::node*' to 'int*' in assignment
```

I can see that `thisNode` has type `node*`, and from the error message I conclude that `next` is a member variable of type `int*`.

Thus, either that declaration is wrong, or your idea of assigning a `node*` to `next` is ill-conceived.

Regarding your second question (which really should be a different question, rather than asking two questions at once), you can either give your struct a constructor, or upgrade to `C++11` and do `new node{*arr, nullptr}`.